# How to use WP_Query to display many posts?

Tags: wp-query, loop

This is my `WP_Query` instruction but this not work. This display just first post. Help me please?

```
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'teachers',
        'p' => '100, 102, 105'          <----------
    );

    // The Query
    $filter = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $filter->have_posts() ) { ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` (post) paremeter for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) accetps a single value only:

```
$args = array(
    'p' => 100
);
```

For multiple posts use `post__in` and pass an array of post ids:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array(100, 102, 105)
);
```

See [Post & Page Paremters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for further clarification.